# Laravel/PDO not escaping backslashes or quotes?

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo

In laravel, I have a search box a user can type into for searching the database.

It executes the following code when submitted (just showing the important parts here).

```
$searchBox = $request->get('searchBox');

...
$getSearch->where(function($query) use($searchBox) {
    $query->orWhere('event', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchBox.'%');
    $query->orWhere('sub_event', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchBox.'%');
});
```

The problem is if the use inputs a double quote (") or a backslash () the query fails. It appears to no be escaping those characters.

If I do this.

```
$searchBox = addslashes($searchBox);
```

Then it works great.

I don't know if this is a laravel or a PDO issue (or not an issue at all).  Do I need to be sanitizing all user input for backslashes? Should I be using addslashes? Or am I not understanding how this is supposed to work.

How do I perform a LIKE search in mysql/PDO/laravel when the search terms contain backslashes or double quotes?

Thanks

*edit

I should have checked what the error I was getting actually was. I have now done that.

I thought it was giving a weird error, because it was giving my webpage redirect loops when I ran the query. But the comment by @David Smith below made me recheck that. Turns out, it was a zero result from the query that was causing the loops.

So sorry, I should have been more clear on that from the beginning. The query doesn't actually 'fail', I just get no results.

But I need people to be able to search comments/fields that may (and do) have backslashes and double quotes in them.

Actually, fixing the loops seems that double quotes now works. Its just backslashes that cause zero results. If I search a phrase that has a backslash, I get no results.

I'm not thinking that is because the query treats the backslash as an escape character, instead of a backslash to search for.

If that's right, then how do I allow my users to search for terms containing a backslash?  Is addslashes still the way to go?

Comment: Laravel doesn't need to escape the data, since it uses parameterized queries. My guess is that the data in your database actually contains the slashes, which it shouldn't.

Comment: You say that "the query fails". What exactly does this mean? Does MySQL return an error, or does the query simply return zero results?

Comment: @DavidSmith You bring a good point, I edited to clarify. Fails means zero results here.

Comment: @patricus Yes, it does contain backslashes. But I'm not sure what you mean by "it shouldn't".  Its user generated comments, I can't demand they don't use backslashes (or at least don't really want to do that).

Comment: it shouldn't contain any **extra** slashes that a user didn't enter.

Comment: @Nertskull From your original post, it sounded like the data in the database included the backslashes used as escape characters. For example, a field that contained the text `it shouldn\'t`. I was saying that escape characters should not be stored in the database. Yes, the user's should be free to enter backslashes if they want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [backslash is a special character for LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), and thus have to be escaped for this operator only.

So if you indeed have to make a careful match for a backslash then process your data to be used in LIKE statement with this code

```
$data = addCslashes($data, '\\');
```

Comment: So should I always be using addCslashes for search fields that use the LIKE operator? This won't interfere with the normal escaping done by PDO queries right?

Comment: Yes, looks like you have to use it. and no, it shouldn't interfere.

Answer (score 6):

If using Laravel, use quad-escapes:

```
// querying for 'Foo\Bar'...
Model::where('backslashes', 'like', 'Foo\\\\Bar')->get()
```

Drove me nuts figuring it out, should be noted in the Laravel docs.